# End Time For Sacrificial Offerings

Tags: sources-mekorot, halacha-theory, korban, bo, mechilta

The verse states, in Exodus 12:10, regarding the eating of the Paschal Offering:

> וְלֹֽא־תוֹתִ֥ירוּ מִמֶּ֖נּוּ עַד־בֹּ֑קֶר וְהַנֹּתָ֥ר מִמֶּ֛נּוּ עַד־בֹּ֖קֶר בָּאֵ֥שׁ תִּשְׂרֹֽפוּ׃
>
> Do not leave any of it over until morning. Anything that is left over until morning must be burned in fire.

The [Mekhilta](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52201&st=&pgnum=163) on this verse (Parshas Bo (Maseches d-Pesach) Parsha 6, Paragraph 37), explains the double use of the word "בֹּקֶר" ("morning"), to be that the verse is prescribing the end time for what is considered "night" in regards to the eating of the Paschal Ofering. In this case, the double usage teaches us that instead of the time ending at Netz Hachama, it ends at Alos Hashachar. The Mekhilta then goes on to state that this verse teaches that night ends at Alos with regards to all other sacrificial offerings and things of that sort that the Torah prescribes as ending with the termination of night.

Why does the Mekhilta extend this possuk to all other sacrifices? It would seem simpler and clearer that the Torah has a specific rule *only* for the Paschal Offering, and not for other offerings, especially given the fact that Netz is generally seen as the end of night bound Mitzvos, (see note 15 in the "Yisron Ha'Ohr" section of the commentary on the Mekhilta that is cited).

Comment: The Beis Halevi answers, (see footnote 18 in "Yisron Ha'Ohr" section of the commentary on the Mekhilta that is cited) that THIS is the limmud for the WHOLE Torah that the day starts from Alos. In fact according to the Beis Halevi, this is the Limmud for the whole Torah that the day starts from Alos, which even strengthens the question, why do we learn that the day starts at Alos from Korban Pesach, when seemingly "Hah Gufa," .... (continued in next comment)

Comment: the fact that the possuk uses extra words to teach us that the day starts from Alos seems to be saying that we would think that the day SHOULD start from neitz, and Korban pesach is different from other mitzvos with this regard. The Beis Halevi extends the limmud of the Mekhilta to the whole Torah, not just other Korbanos, and that could be a seperate question, how could the B"H do that?